# Find values from one redis set which don't belong in another

Tags: redis

In redis, I have two sets, `A` and `B`.

I want to find which values from `A` are not already in `B`.

If I do `SDIFF`, my understanding is that it shows me the differences (like an outer join) of both. But I only want to know which from `A` is not already in `B`.

Is there a command to do this or do i need to loop through `A` and check if it's in  `B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SDIFF` is the command you're looking for. If you look at the example in [the documentation](https://redis.io/commands/sdiff) you'll see that it acts in the way you're describing:

```
key1 = {a,b,c,d}
key2 = {c}
key3 = {a,c,e}
SDIFF key1 key2 key3 = {b,d}
```